# Memory offsets in assembly listing file

Tags: memory, assembly

I'm trying to learn assembly and have the following snippet from assembly code/listing file (for x86 32bit):

[image]

Can anyone explain why line 50 in the listing file section has a memory offset of 11? I feel like it should be 17 since the first string takes up 17 bytes. Thanks.

Comment: `1A` should've been a hint here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those memory offsets are in [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

17 decimal = 0x11 (hexadecimal)

Pretty much any time you're dealing with addresses in a computer, they will be shown in hex. As 16 is a power of two, it just makes more sense than base 10.

Comment: No problem. Beginner's mistake.